# Laravel Blade Layout View [layout.default] not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've just started using "Laravel". But the code snippets isn't working.

inside my DemoController.php

```
<?php class DemoController extends BaseController
{   
    public $restful = true;

    public $layout = 'layout.default';  

    public function get_index() 
    {       
        $this->layout->title = 'laravelpage';

        $View = View::make('demo1.index' , array(
            'name'=>'Laravel user',              
            'age'=>'28',            
            'location'=>'dhaka'));

        $this->layout->content = $View; 
    }
}
```

and inside my index.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 

        <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>  

        {{ $content }}

    </body>
</html>
```

my route is:

```
Route::controller('demo1','DemoController');
```

why it's showing this error?
[image: showing this error]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You added `@extends('layouts.default')` or something? I believe you meant "Blade" and not "Baldey".

Comment: I do not know if I'm confused, but the right would not you use "default.blade.php" instead of "index.blade.php"

Comment: I didn't add `@extends('layouts.default')` , do I need to? but I now have renamed the file to `default.blade.php` inside app->view->demo1, still not working

Comment: Using controller layouts is an implicit version of `@extends` in Blade - see my answer for more detail on what's going on. It may be worth nothing to aks007 that maybe you should ignore controller layouts and use Blade view inheritance (explicit `@extends` in views) as there's slightly less magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean Blade Layout ?

First,instead of **get_index**, use just **index** method name in you controller.
Second, try to use **resourceful controllers** - mapping from your route 
to you domain logic will be much more clear, and you'll have whole resource generated. For that purpose use great [laravel generator package.](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Generator)

Third, I dont see any connection between your blade variables and provided array ?

Using generators is optional, just a good practice.

Better solution is:

```
public function index()
{

    $my_array ["title"=>"some_title","content"=>"some_content"];
    return View::make("my_view")->with("my_array",$my_array); 
    //or
    return View::make("my_view",compact("my_array"));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Besides other things that can go wrong in you app (permissions,laravel version...), you need to follow very basic pattern in order this to work:

Create a new route with:

```
Route::get("demo1","DemoController@index");
```

Create a new view (index.blade.php file) in your views folder (or subfolder).

Create a new controller:

```
class DemoController extends BaseController{

    public function index()
    {
        $my_array = ["title"=>"some_title","content"=>"some_content"];
        return View::make("index")->with("my_array",$my_array);

    }
}
```

And in index.blade.php you can put something like:

```
{{$title}}
{{$content}}
```

Now go to browser and you should see title and content, after refresh.
I guess your server settings are right.

Comment: it's not resolving showing another error, could you give the full working code and edit your answer? thanks

Comment: I don't feel like this answer is actually answering the quesiton at hand. First it starts going on about resourceful controllers and a generator package, then it tells the OP to undo everything they've done and do it from scratch some other way which, while maybe the best way to start learning, actually goes against what they have and want to achieve. Also the bottom code sample is incorrect - that controller action will give one variable in the view `my_array` which has two keys, rather than the two variables the answer suggests. (Sorry to be blunt.)

Answer (score 2):

As I read your question, you actually need two views here:

1. layout/default.blade.php
2. demo1/index.blade.php

That's why it says the view cannot be found - you've created the second of those two views and you're using it in your controller's action, however you don't appear to have created the layout's view that you refer to in the controller.

Furthermore, you're actually trying to access the layout variables (`title` and `content`) in your inner view and not your layout. The variables available to each view are as follows:

- layout.default:

  - title (laravelpage)
  - content (the HTML of the demo1.index view)
- demo1.index

  - name (Laravel user)
  - age (28)
  - location (dhaka)

Comment: hi, i have also this issue..in browser it simply prints {{ $name }} and in my laravel app there are no files like "layout/default.blade.php" is it preloaded or we have to create it?

Comment: It's probably worth you posting this as a fresh question Hiren, You will be able to include relevant code snippets too so people can better help you.